# how to correctly format WideString using sprintf or wprintf

Tags: printf, widestring, c++builder-2010

I am using this code to format WideString but with no success! It prints unexpecting results :(

here is my code

```
WideString s;
dep=new TStringList();
while(!DM->tDepPln->Eof)
    {
    //where tDepPlnFltNo is mysql field type of WideString
        s.sprintf(L"%-11S",DM->tDepPlnFltNo->AsWideString);
        dep->Add(s);
        DM->tDepPln->Next();
    }
```

when I use `s.sprintf(L"%-11S","blablabla");` it works but when i set to mysql field type of WideString it's not!!
I think the problem is with conversion!

How to correct it ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format specifier is using uppercase `S`, which tells Unicode flavors of `...printf()` functions (such as the one used inside of `WideString:::sprintf()`) to expect a `char*` instead of a `wchar_t*` (and Ansi flavors of `...printf()` functions to expect a `wchar_t*` instead of a `char*`).  That is why `s.sprintf(L"%-11S","blablabla")` works - you are passing it a `char*`.

For what you are attempting, you need to use lowercase `s` instead.  You also need to use the `WideString::c_bstr()` method when passing a `WideString` value to a `...printf()` function, eg:

```
s.sprintf(L"%-11s", DM->tDepPlnFltNo->AsWideString.c_bstr());
```

Comment: You are right Remy! I used to use lowercase `s` and I often use it in AnsiString. And I know that I have used upper S because I saw printf() func with upper S in the following site. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/0300__Wide-Character-String/OutputwidecharacterstringwithSinprintf.htm Thought WideString sprintf also uses this but not.

Comment: Thanks Remy for your help! It works `WideString(fieldAsWS).c_bstr();`